# ES6 arrow function and this context

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have read some topics on arrow function, but below code just confuses me.

```
var bunny = {
  name: 'Usagi',
  tasks: ['transform', 'eat cake', 'blow kisses'],
  first : () => {
    console.log(this) //does not refer to bunny
  },
  second: function(){
    console.log(this) //refers to bunny
  },
  third() {
    this.tasks.forEach((task) => {
      console.log(this); //refers to bunny
    });
  }
};

bunny.first();
bunny.second();
bunny.third();
```

Can anyone tell me how come third function inner function this refers to current object, while the first one does not. **Is it not when we use arrow function, this refers to current scope where it is defined?**

Comment: arrow functions don't define a `this` in their own lexical scope, so it gets it from its outer scope, just like it would get a normal variable not defined within itself.

Comment: The current `this` context inside property expressions of an object literal is not the constructed object.

Comment: See [Arrow function vs function declaration / expressions: Are they equivalent / exchangeable?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/34361379/218196)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) are more or less equivalent to `function` statements, *except* that they bind the `this` argument to that of the parent scope.

In other words, if an arrow function appears in the top scope, its `this` argument will always refer to the global scope (e.g., `window` in browsers or `global` in node.js), while an arrow function inside a regular function will have its `this` argument the same as its outer function, as your code demostrates.

Comment: Isn't the outer fn forEach? And the value of `this` attached to it isn't `this.tasks`? Can anyone give a more step-by-step explanation?